# Request for analysis of vote count on both global and minor scale

Tags: feature-request, statistics, voting, data-analysis

Can we get a total number of vote casted on stackoverflow for each day that the site existed?

I want to see some analysis done to attempt to answer questions like:

- (Inflation/deflation) Is a vote now worth more than a vote then?
- (Weekly fluctuation) Are significantly less votes cast on weekends?

We're geeks. We like charts and statistics. Let's do it!

---

Ideally the votes should be divided into the 4 obvious categories, `QUp`, `QDown`, `AUp`, `ADown`. Then we can analyze things like:

- Does the introduction of {Electorate} shift the ratio of `QTotal` and `ATotal`?

  - Is that the intent? Is there a desired balance by design?
- What about the ratio of `UpTotal` and `DownTotal`?
- etc

Comment: Too bad that http://statoverflow.com/sandbox and http://stackql.net are dead. You'll have to install [a DB](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx) and play with [the data](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/1088-apr-2010) yourself, assuming you know a bit [SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/).

Answer (score 1):

We need someone to sponsor an OData Trilogy dump site.

This is something I talked about with Scott Hanselman, and he expressed interest in hosting it on Azure with Microsoft's support.. would be an ideal case!

Comment: Cool, looking toward it.